# How can I have both a parameterized and a default constructor in the same class?

Tags: c++, function, class

I am attempting to write a class called student that has both a paramaterized and a default constructor  in it, and the paramaterized version works fine, but the console crashes whenever I attempt to run the default constructor after assigning values manually.

Student.cpp:

```
Student::Student()
{
    this -> firstName = firstName;
    this -> lastName = lastName;
    this -> maxGrades = maxGrades;
    grades[maxGrades];
}

Student::Student(string fName, string lName, int mGrades)
{
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    maxGrades = mGrades;
    grades[maxGrades];
}

Student::~Student()
{

}

void Student::setFirstName(string fName)
{
    firstName = fName;
}

void Student::setLastName(string lName)
{
    lastName = lName;
}

void Student::setMaxGrades(int mGrades)
{
    mGrades = maxGrades;
    grades[maxGrades];
}

string Student::getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

string Student::getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

void Student::addGrade(int currentGradeNumber, double addedGrade)
{
    if(currentGradeNumber < maxGrades)
    {
        grades[currentGradeNumber] = addedGrade;
        cout << "grade " << currentGradeNumber << "is " << grades[currentGradeNumber] << endl;
    }
}

double Student::calcAvg()
{
    double sum = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < maxGrades;i++)
    {
        sum += grades[i];
    }
    avg = sum/maxGrades;
    return avg;
}
```

studentTest.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    Student student1("Bill", "Nye", 3);
    cout << "First Name: " << student1.getFirstName() << endl;
    cout << "LastName: " << student1.getLastName() << endl;
    student1.addGrade(0, 90);
    student1.addGrade(1, 95);
    student1.addGrade(2, 80);
    cout << "Average is " << student1.calcAvg() << endl;

    Student student2;
    student2.setMaxGrades(2);
    student2.setFirstName("Frank");
    student2.setLastName("West");
    cout << "\nFirst Name: " << student2.getFirstName() << endl;
    cout << "Last Name: " << student2.getLastName() << endl;
    student2.addGrade(0,50);
    student2.addGrade(1,100);
    cout << "Average is: " << student2.calcAvg();
    return 0;
}
```

student.h:

```
class Student
{
    private:
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        int maxGrades;
        int numGrades;
        double grades[];
    public:
        Student();
        Student(string, string, int);
        ~Student();
        void setFirstName(string);
        void setLastName(string);
        string getFirstName();
        string getLastName();
        void addGrade(int, double);
        double calcAvg();
        void setMaxGrades(int);
};
```

The student1 object runs fine, but the error comes when I try to use addGrade() or calcAvg() for student2. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but your default constructor makes no sense and doesn't actually initialize anything.  How about sharing the actual error message

Comment: Can you share your header file so we can see how your class's members are declared?

Comment: Also, all the `grades[maxGrades]` aren't valid array allocations, instead they are no-ops (probably with a hint of undefined behavior).

Comment: @JoeZ I added the header file in my edit.

Comment: @EdS There is no error message in the compiler, i just get student.exe has stopped working from windows.

Answer (score 4):

Both your constructors are incorrect when they do this:

```
grades[maxGrades]; // This does not do what you think it does
```

This line does not crash in the parameterized constructor because `maxGrades` has a known value. Your default constructor, however, reuses an uninitialized value of `maxGrades`, causing undefined behavior.

You should rewrite your constructors using initializer lists. Assuming that `grades` is a `std::vector<int>`, you can do it like this:

```
Student::Student() : maxGrades(0)
{
// The remaining members will be initialized, because they have constructors.
}

Student::Student(string fName, string lName, int mGrades)
:   firstName(fName)
,   lastName(lName)
,   maxGrades(mGrades)
,   grades(mGrades, 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does nothing useful:

```
this -> firstName = firstName;
this -> lastName = lastName;
this -> maxGrades = maxGrades;
```

Because you're in a method of your class, both `this->firstName` and `firstName` refer to the same variable—the same *member* variables.  Likewise for the other two statements.

Without seeing how those members are declared, it's hard to say if this is the reason for your crash.  But, it's definitely bogus code.

Also, this line does nothing useful as well:

```
grades[maxGrades];
```

And depending on how `maxGrades` and `grades` are declared, it is quite likely the source of your crash.

**Edit:**  Your declaration for `grades` doesn't look good at all, because it's not allocating any storage for grades.  You should consider using a `std::vector<double>` here, or at least specify a maximum size larger than the largest data set you'll be asked to work with.  (eg. `double grades[100];`)  But seriously, consider `std::vector<double>` here.

In your default constructor, you should assign reasonable default values to each of the members in an initializer list.  Something like this:

```
Student::Student() :
    firstName(""),
    lastName(""),
    maxGrades(0),
    numGrades(0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is called and whatever within in it is initialized **as soon as the object** is created. You are assigning values to first, maxgrade etc. *only after* creation of object. I don't think this is right.

Answer (score 0):

Since grades is just a pointer, you are not allocating memory to it with the constructor lines "grades[maxGrades];".  You have to do something like grades = new double[maxGrades], and only on a defined maxGrades (not defined in your default constructor).  You could be doing a divide by zero in your average (if maxGrades = 0), and accessing an uninitialized pointer, grades.  You need a way to set a default value to maxGrades, and then you need to do the "new" allocation of memory for grades.

Your function

```
void Student::setMaxGrades(int mGrades)
{
    mGrades = maxGrades;
    grades[maxGrades];
}
```

should read

```
maxGrades = mGrades; 
grades = new double[maxGrades];
```